# Android: Parceling List of Objects

Tags: android, parcelable

I am writing a code for an android app, where if one clicks on an element of a list, it opens a new list of objects unique to it, as shown below.

```
public class A{    
public int id;   
public String name;   
}   

public class B{       
public String name;   
public List<A> a;   
}
```

How do i parcel the class B from one ListActivity to another?

this would be my parceling code for B:-

```
public A(Parcel in){

    name = in.readString();     
    in.readList(a, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeList(a);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<B> CREATOR = new Creator<B>() {

    @Override
    public B[] newArray(int size) {

        return new B[size];
    }

    @Override
    public B createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new B(source);
    }
};
```

and my parcel code for A:-

```
public A(){};

public A(Parcel in){

    id = in.readLong();
    name = in.readString(); 

}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeLong(id);
    dest.writeString(name);



}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<A> CREATOR = new Creator<A>() {

    @Override
    public A[] newArray(int size) {

        return new A[size];
    }

    @Override
    public A createFromParcel(Parcel source) {

        return new A(source);
    }
};
```

these don't work and cause my app to crash while trying to open the new list activity.

New ListActivity Code:-

```
    private B b; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.MainList);
    Bundle bun = getIntent().getExtras();
    b = bun.getParcelable(".modle.B");


    ArrayAdapter<A> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<A>     (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,b.a);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: questions is too long. didn't read. alos formatting is bad, no stacktrace etc.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: you need to show your stacktrace mister.